# Google Maps change Marker data without deleting/creating (MarkerWithLabel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to change the "labelContent" and "labelClass" dynamically without deleting the marker and creating a new one.

I know you can use `markersArray[i].setIcon("new-icon.png");` to change the icon. Are there equivalents for the above?

My marker:

```
    marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: loc,
        map: map,
        visible: true,
        labelContent: "999",
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(30, 33),
        labelClass: "test-label",
        labelStyle: {opacity: 1.0},
        icon: "image1.png"

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
markersArray[i]['labelContent'] = 'new content';
markersArray[i]['icon'] = 'new-icon.png';
```

work?

Comment: I had no luck with the above :(

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't forcing the marker to be redrawn with     `markersArray[i].label.setStyles();`

Now it works:

```
markersArray[i].labelClass = 'labels-new-class';
markersArray[i].label.setStyles();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating marker dynamically
I get this snippet also from **stackoverflow**
but forgot the link.. and still searching
this is sample to call function to change title of marker
try your experiment with **"labelContent" and "labelClass"**
and let us know...

```js
var map;
function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 12,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-7.045000, 110.426000),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP 
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
setMarkers(map, markers);
};

var markers = [['MSC SEMARANG', -7.045000, 110.426000, 1107, '../images/tower2.png'], ['Srondol', -7.062000, 110.418000, 1108, '../images/tower2.png']];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          var markers = locations[i];
          var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: locations[i][0],
            zIndex: locations[i][3],
            icon: locations[i][4]
          });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              changeTitle(this);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
      };

      function changeTitle(x) {
        var count = 0;
          var titles = x.get('title');
          x.set('title', 'this is chaged');
      };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Hope this help...